# what type shall use to store 12 digit value shall I use decimal or nvarchar in SQL DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I need to store an CARD ID number in Database. So there is no calculation just a search of the ID and putting the value in Session as property in a class.

The is ID is always numeric and it's 12 positions.
e.g. 123456789012 and I would like to show on the screen in this format. 123.456.789.012  (every 3 digit a dot).

I tried a test and defined Decimal(12,0) in database and I have put this value in database: 555666777888

then I try to display on the screen I used this code  (CardID is decimal):

```
  lblCardID.Text = ent.CardID.ToString("0:#,###")
```

but it shows on the screen like this: **555,666,77:7,888**

where is the **colon (:)** coming from?

question additional:
- What type shall use in MS SQL to store this value in Database. Decimal (12,0) or Nvarchar(12) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`bigint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933198%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) because it needs only 8 bytes per value.

[`decimal(12,0)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258832%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) needs 9 bytes and `varchar` or `nvarchar` even more (12 or 24 bytes respectively in case of storing 12 digits).

Smaller column size makes indexes smaller, which make indexes faster in use.

Formatting numbers can be done in application. 
It's also much easier to change formatting in app in case of requirements change.

Comment: what would be the property definition in the class Int64? long?

Comment: Yes. MS-SQL `bigint` type is mapped to `long` .NET type.

Comment: this answer is more appreciated, because here I also learnt why bigint is preferable over decimal(12,0).

Answer (score 4):

`nvarchar` is definitely not needed.  if it's always 12 digits, `char(12)` would be fine, but I think a 64-bit integer would be most appropriate.

Comment: Yes, a 64-bit integer can hold up to 18 digits.

Comment: @Jeremy: why do you "also" propose char? it's 12 digit number always. Even some other colleauges propose char?

Comment: @mesut: to be clear, I do not propose a char, I propose a 64-bit integer.  But NVARCHAR is unicode (twice the storage space to support an extended character set, which you will not need since you're only using numbers), plus it has overhead to allow for a variable length of characters, which you do not have.

Comment: thanks.. this is useful I got your point. NVARCHAR is useless in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Try writing

```
lblCardID.Text = ent.CardID.ToString("#,###")
```

You can user the `decimal(12,0)` or the `bigint` datatype. `bigint` requires one byte less (8 bytes total) per stored value.

Comment: I didn't know the "BigInt". Since there is no decimal and always 12 digit numeric wouldn't be better to use "bigint"?

Comment: usefull answer, because it fixed my issue with (.) separator.

Comment: Yes, bigint is in terms of number of bytes a bit better. It requires 8 bytes. decimal(12) will require 9 bytes per value. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The colon is coming from the colon in your format string.  The "0:" at the beginning of the format string is needed when you are using string.Format(), as a placeholder to identify which of the arguments to format, but not if you are using ToString() (since there's only one value being formatted).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store the formatting, and it's just a numeric value, use varchar, don't waste time with nvarchar as it increases your storage size and won't do you any good unless you expect special (international) chars

Answer (score 0):

If it's never going to be calculated on, I would store it as char(12).

Then in your code, split it with something like this and use the replace function to convert commas to dots:

`lblCardID.Text = ent.CardID.ToString("#,###").Replace(",", ".")`

Answer (score 0):

If it's an ID number store it as a string datatype, you're not going to be doing sums on it, you also won't have problems losing any leading zeros. You could also then store the card id with the embedded dots, sorting out your formatting problems.

Answer (score 0):

Does your identifier's domain have matematical properties, other than being composed of digits? If not, your value is fixed width, so use `CHAR(12)`. Do not forget to add appropriate domain checks (no characters other than digits, no leading zero, etc) e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE Cards 
(
 card_ID CHAR(12) NOT NULL
    UNIQUE
    CONSTRAINT card_ID__all_digits 
       CHECK (card_ID NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'), 
    CONSTRAINT card_ID__no_leading_zero
       CHECK (card_ID NOT LIKE '[1-9]%)')
);
```